# Can't find an obvious match in a string in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, match

```
Node -v
v18.17.1
```

*Note: Both Phrase and Title used in this question are both raw strings copied from source*

There is a phrase and a title. I want to check if the phrase is available in a title.
Obviously enough it is available but JS is responding like no matches found I don't know why (it does not work) eg:

[image]

However when I do not use variables, When i copy the phrase and the title values and run them directly the match is being found (it works) eg:

```js
let title = 'Benny Blanco, Halsey & Khalid - Eastside (Lyrics)';

title = title.toLowerCase();

let phrase = 'benny blanco';

console.log('match:', title.includes(phrase) === true ? 'found' : '404'); 

// it is working
```

At first I thought it was just a spaces problem but I tried normalizing the spaces with `collapseWhitespace()` method available in the [strings package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string#--collapsewhitespace) and yet nothing changed.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: FYI: `includes()` already returns `true` or `false`, this means that `=== true` is obsolete

Comment: does your phrase have a blank at the end?

Comment: You've provided some code that appears to be working - that won't let us help you with the code that is *not* working - can you provide that?

Comment: try using `.trim()`

Comment: @NinaScholz No. Both title and phrase are being normalized in terms of extra spaces.

Comment: @freedomn-m Both title and phrase are being trimmed and turned to lower case.

Comment: @Reyno What are you saying? I use `===` for comparison always. It's a habit.

Comment: Reyno is saying `if ((1===1) === true)` is not *needed* - if it's a style issue then carry on.

Comment: You've only stated (in the question, and no evidence in the code) that you've used `collapseWhitespace()` - this does *not* *trim* spaces, it only reduces concurrent spaces, eg `".."` -> `"."` (where `.` represents a space) - your console.log (in the screenshot) does not show if there's a space at the end.

Comment: In the code that doesn't work, where are the values for title/phrase taken from?

Comment: @freedomn-m Let me try that and update the question. Though I specifically tried the `trim()` method also.

Comment: No worries - if you tried it you tried it - just want to be clear of the distinction between collapse and trim

Comment: @freedomn-m the values are from database and the phrase is an input from user.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using VS Code, so if you're declaring the title manually in your code (for instance copy-pasted from somewhere else) ensure you have this option enabled:

> Editor › Unicode Highlight: Invisible Characters
>
> [v] Controls whether characters that just reserve space or have no width at all are highlighted.

Alternatively you can try this:

1. Count the characters in your phrase.
2. Cut out the part of the title since beginning till the length of the phrase.
3. Print the output of the cut out part to the console and compare that directly with the phrase.

If they still look identical, you can also try:

1. For both: phrase and cut out part of the title, transform them to arrays, map the arrays changing each character to it's representing Unicode with [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and compare the outputs of both arrays. If the strings are different indeed you should find the differences in the arrays at some positions.

Comment: Hey. You have suggested some useful tips. I will give you my feedback once I try these approaches.